# Websocket data is appearing in an h1 element, but not in an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a Binance API project for getting the live price of Bitcoin. I wrote some Javascript code to do this.

The issue is that it is not working in an `input` but it is working in a `h1`. I need it to work in the `input`. How can I do this?

```html
<h1 id="btc-price"></h1>
<input type="text" id="btc-price" value="" />
```

```js
let weburl = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade');
let stockPriceElement = document.getElementById('btc-price');
let lastPrice = null;

weburl.onmessage = (event) => {
  let stockObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
  let price = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);
  stockPriceElement.style.color = !lastPrice || lastPrice === price ? 'black' : price > lastPrice ? 'green' : 'red';
  stockPriceElement.innerText = price;
  lastPrice = price;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you've created two HTML elements with the same `id`, which is invalid. `id` must be unique. In addition, the method used to update the content of an `h1` and an `input` are different.

To set the value of the `input`, select it from the DOM and set its `value` property, like this:

```js
let weburl = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade');
let stockPriceInput = document.querySelector('#btc-price');
let lastPrice = null;

weburl.onmessage = (event) => {
  let stockObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
  let price = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);
  stockPriceInput.style.color = !lastPrice || lastPrice === price ? 'black' : price > lastPrice ? 'green' : 'red';
  stockPriceInput.value = price;  
  lastPrice = price;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="btc-price" value="" />
```

Comment: I dont want result in <h1 id="btc-price"></h1>. I only need result in <input type="text" id="btc-price-input" value="" />. If <input> alone, it is not working. I need to add <h1> also.. Please check..

Comment: Yes it does. I removed the `h1` to save any confusion.